# Python module name aliases?

Tags: python

I've got a module called 'cloud.aws.boto'. I need this to import the boto library I installed into my virtualenv.

If I add `import boto.ec2` to my 'cloud.aws.boto.py' file, python complains because it's trying to import 'ec2' from the local file instead of the library in my virtualenv.

How can I import another module with the same name as the one I'm importing from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

You can try to remove `"."` from `sys.path` just before this import (but don't forget to prepend it back once you are done, otherwise you won't be able to imnport your other local modules).

Comment: Yuck. Ugly but I guess it'll do the job